# Typescript object property asserts something about other properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object. I use it to store the data I receive from API.
This object looks like this:

```
class Store {
   isLoaded: boolean = false;
   data: object || null = null;
}
```

Now I know that if `isLoaded` is false `data` will be `null`. If `isData` is true, then `data` will be `object`. How should I type this efficiently?

I could make from `isLoaded`, that would check if `data` is `null`. That would be awesome, but sometimes those objects are too dynamic to be easily checked.

I could do this:

```
const store = new Store() as ({isLoaded: false, data:null} | {isLoaded: true, data: object});
```

But that is somewhat cumbersome, especially for larger objects.

What I would like is something like this:

```
class Store {
   _isLoaded: boolean = false;
   data: object | null = null;
   get isLoaded(): typeof this.data is object {
       return this_isLoaded();
   }
```

Thanks for any tips.

EDIT:
Just for clarification (I'm sorry if my question is not clear enough.).
I'm trying to solve this problem:

```
class Store {
   isLoaded: boolean = false;
   data: {prop:string} || null = null;
   load = () => {
       this.data = {prop: "value"};
       this.isLoaded = true;
   }
}
let store = new Store();
store.load();
if (store.isLoaded) {
    console.log(store.data.prop); // Now typescript thinks that store.data can be null and throws an error
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfourtunatelly it is not possible to do this on getters, though it is possible in methods.

```
interface LoadedStore {
  data: object
  isLoaded(): true
}

class Store {
  private _isLoaded: boolean = false
  data: object | null = null

  isLoaded(): this is LoadedStore {
    return this._isLoaded
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood the question right, but based on the fact that your class is a Store, it may store different kind of objects right?

Thinking in this way, I can only think about a generic abstract class representing the store, and then I would extend this abstract class to each of the products that my store may have.

I created a playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-sD-l+uRxmk4nez3d7-cHvkjXMj459Za6h3y88gDApLOxKnk+C2CHRh4Cul3iBjlIAQpzT+eD1ir-k74eB8N15+sckqx2dcqD-CB7wAzYgO0IA) representing my point of view

```js
abstract class Store<T> {
    private _isLoaded: boolean = false;
    abstract data: T | null;

    get isLoaded(): boolean {
        return this._isLoaded;
    }

    set isLoaded(v: boolean) {
        this._isLoaded = v;
    }


    abstract load(): Promise<void>;
    abstract show(): void;
}
```

Here we have the abstract class implementation, you can see that data is abstract and the type is either T or null.

```js
interface IProduct {
    name: string;
    value: number;
    stock: number;
}
```

Then this interface represents an item of our store

```js
class ProductA extends Store<IProduct> {
    data: IProduct | null = null; 

    async load(): Promise<void> {
        // load data from db if succesfull set isLoaded to true
        super.isLoaded = true;
        this.data = {
            name: 'product',
            value: 2,
            stock: 10,
        }
    }

    show() {
        if (super.isLoaded) {
            console.log(this.data);
        } else {
            console.log('null');
        }
    }
}
```

And here we can extend Store and the methods to fetch and show the data

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but that will be the way I will approach a store problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple and just do it like that:

```js
type Store = {
    isLoaded: true; 
    data: object; // Should maybe vary to Record<string, unknown>
} | {
    isLoaded: false;
    data: null;
};
```

i see no problems in using an or in a type as it always should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the interface. For example:

```js
interface IStore {
    isLoaded: boolean;
    data: object | null;
}

class Store implements IStore {
   isLoaded: boolean = false;
   data: object || null = null;
}
```

"One of the most common uses of interfaces in languages like C# and Java, that of explicitly enforcing that a class meets a particular contract, is also possible in TypeScript." - more info: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#class-types